# How to override a camelCased model file in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a shipping community model that has a camel cased class/file witch I would like to override.

The original file/class is located under **app/code/community/PedroTeixeira/Correios/Model/Carrier/CorreiosMethod.php** and I would like to override a method of this file, or the whole class under **app/code/local/Esmart/CorreiosImprovements/Model/Carrier/CorreiosMethod.php**.

In the **original module config file**, I can see it's model declaration in config.xml as follows:

```
<global>
...
    <models> 
        <pedroteixeira_correios>
            <class>PedroTeixeira_Correios_Model</class>
        </pedroteixeira_correios>
    </models>
...
    <sales>
        <shipping>
            <carriers>
                <pedroteixeira_correios>
                    <class>PedroTeixeira_Correios_Model_Carrier_CorreiosMethod</class>
                </pedroteixeira_correios>
            </carriers>
        </shipping>
    </sales>
</global>
```

At **my module** config.xml I've declared the override this way:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <esmart_correiosimprovements>
            <class>Esmart_CorreiosImprovements_Model</class>
        </esmart_correiosimprovements>

        <pedroteixeira_correios>
            <rewrite>
                <carrier_correiosMethod>Esmart_CorreiosImprovements_Model_Carrier_CorreiosMethod</carrier_correiosMethod>
            </rewrite>
        </pedroteixeira_correios>
    </models>
</global>
```

Usually the model file isn't camel cased, so I guess it's easier. Or am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class group (`<pedroteixeira_correios>`) to use in your rewrite syntax depends on the class group declaration in the module's config.

The class ID (`<carrier_correiosMethod>`) to use in your rewrite syntax depends entirely on how the class is invoked in the code. For your example, the following would all instantiate the *original* class instance on *case-sensitive* filesystems:

- `pedroteixeira_correios/carrier_correiosMethod`
- `pedroteixeira_correios/Carrier_correiosMethod`
- `pedroteixeira_correios/carrier_CorreiosMethod`
- `pedroteixeira_correios/Carrier_CorreiosMethod`

On case-insensitive filesystems, any combination of casing for the class ID part would yield the model instance. Hopefully the extension vendor followed a consistent pattern when specifying their class in code/markup, but you can specify multiple xpaths using the list above to handle all permutations.

Comment: Hi @benmarks. Thank you for replying. It's nice to hear from you again. =) I guess I missed an important part of the original module declaration in my question, witch regards to the declaration of CorreiosMethod class. But I still didn't find the error on my rewrite. Does the additional info helps you to help me? =)

Comment: Ah. You cannot rewrite that the way it's written. Without a / in classname argument, the class is instantiated directly. Your options are to redefine the `sales/shipping/carriers/pedroteixeira_correios/class` node to use your class, use class group notation and hence the rewrite.